# Python recursive to NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js

I've got the following recursive/loop in Python:

```
''.join([x+y for x,y in zip(s[1::2], s[0::2])])
```

Which swaps nibbles on `s`.

I'm trying to replicate it as simple as possible in NodeJS, but are new in NodeJS. The recursive loop build in and zip makes it difficult.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sample? Please think of this as one of several answers.

```
s.filter((e,i)=>{return i%2==1}).map((e,i)=>{return e+s.filter((e,i)=>{return i%2==0})[i]}).join('');
```

When this is separated by each part, it can be written as follows.

```
var even = s.filter((e,i)=>{return i%2==1});
var odd = s.filter((e,i)=>{return i%2==0});
var zip = even.map((e,i)=>{return e+odd[i]});
var result = zip.join('');
console.log(result);
```

- In this sample script, each loop for the array was expressed by `filter()` and `map()`.
- `s.filter((e,i)=>{return i%2==1})` retrieves elements at even numbers.

  - `s[1::2]` of your script can be expressed by this.
- `s.filter((e,i)=>{return i%2==0})` retrieves elements at odd numbers.

  - `s[0::2]` of your script can be expressed by this.
- `zip()` of your script can be expressed by `even.map((e,i)=>{return e+odd[i]})`.

  - `e+odd[i]` means `x+y` of your script.
- `zip.join('')` means `''.join(` of your script.

#### References :

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

#### Demo

- [python demo](https://ideone.com/pTxpfd)
- [javascript demo](https://jsfiddle.net/et2jcgv1/)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.